# Dell XPS 13 Ultrabook Brightness Control

Tags: arch-linux

I wasn't able to get the brightness working. So far I've tried:

> 1. Controlling via /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0
>
>    - max brightness was 15
>    - does not respond to "echo 5 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness"
>    - "cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/actual_brightness" shows 5 but have no effect
> 2. Controlling via /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight
>
>    - changing the brightness value will result in screen flicker
>    - have to max it out to get rid of the flicker

Does anyone have arch working on this model? I'm lost.

Answer (score 1):

### Backlight

Hi, you can try *xbacklight*. For example,

```
# xbacklight = 20
```

where the value ranges from *0* to *100*

It should come along with the *xorg-apps* package. If not, you can get it from *extra*

```
# sudo pacman -S xorg-xbacklight
```

---

### Graphic Driver

Do make sure you have installed the correct graphic driver for you notebook, or else your xbacklight will give you an error message *"No outputs have backlight property"*

Refer to [Dell](http://www.dell.com/us/p/xps-13-l321x/pd), your notebook uses Intel® HD Graphics 3000

The correct [graphic driver](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_Guide#Install_a_video_driver) to install will be *xf86-video-intel* (64-bit) and *lib32-intel-dri* (32-bit).

If you are installing your Archlinux in 64 bit, you can do the following:

```
# sudo pacman -S xf86-video-intel lib32-intel-dri
```

If you are installing your Archlinux in 32 bit, you can do the following:

```
# sudo pacman -S lib32-intel-dri
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a temporary [workaround script available at the Arch Linux forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1193772#p1193772) — all credit to [tyler.heck](https://bbs.archlinux.org/profile.php?id=56534) I'm just posting it below.

> through trial and error I've found that I need to set /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness to 0 before changes to /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness will affect actual screen brightness. You will need to do this regardless of whether the intel_backlight/brightness is already set to zero, the act of setting the value is what allows the acpi_video0 interface to change the brightness.

---

```
#!/bin/bash

# set intel interface to 0, allowing acpi interface to take precedence
echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness

# set the permissions of the acpi brightness file for convenience of non-root modification
# (works if user is a member of the video group)
chgrp video /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
chmod 664 /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness

# initialize brightness to a low level
echo 3 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness

exit 0
```